# chmod setuid giving operation not permission even though the I am the owner

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

```
shivanshu@<host> ls -l hello.sh 
-rw-r-xr-x 1 shivanshu users 63 Sep  7 17:34 hello.sh
```

So I am clearly the owner of the file. I am able to change normal permissions like r, w, x using chmod command. However, when I try to do setuid on this file, I get an error

```
shivanshu@<host> chmod u+s hello.sh
shivanshu@<host> chmod: changing permissions of 'hello.sh': Operation not permitted
```

Note that I tried it with sudo, as well as with other files like text files instead of .sh files.

Why is this happening? I cannot figure it out based on doing some google search

P.S. - Comment on stack overflow post told me to post here

Comment: Is the file on a filesystem that supports the setuid permission, and has it been mounted with the 'nosuid' option?

Comment: I do not know that since its a pre-configured work system, I can see that files like /usr/bin/passwd have the setuid permission, other than that, how can I check if the directory I am working in supports suid or not? Thanks

Comment: Start by looking at `findmnt`, such as `findmnt -T . -u`, to see the filesystem type and all mount options. Keep in mind /usr is not necessarily going to be the same mount or filesystem as your data directory, _especially_ on a pre-configured work system.

Comment: oh ok, i just tried findmnt -T . -u and the return value specify nosuid in the OPTIONS column. So this means I cannot do chmod u+s, g+s etc on any type of file. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Don't cross post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77085856

Comment: @GillesQuénot i was asked to post here

Comment: Yes, but you should have removed the so post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found out, the filesystem that your files are on has been deliberately mounted with the 'nosuid' option to disable usage of setuid/setgid, presumably as a security precaution.

In addition to that, Linux only honors the setuid bit on compiled (ELF) executables – not on scripts. Even though you can "chmod u+s" a script, it will have no effect when that script is run.

Finally, Bash deliberately drops all unwanted privileges on startup, so even if setuid *did* work on scripts in general, it still would not work on scripts that use #!/bin/bash.